# exe file generated by pyinstaller is not working on other pc

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller, incompatibletypeerror

I generated an exe file from pyinstaller. is working on the same machine (windows 10)
but is not working on others machine giving me this error:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

Same after troubleshooting.

Any help?

Comment: What are the two computers' system information, 32 bit or 64?